# CodeFirst (Only Table structure) from Database

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

**EDITI**

I can't use (DTOs) or the Entiti from my WebApi, because it's not MVC .NET, its PHP and Doctrine. I really can't see a way to do it without "duplicate" code.

I have an PHP Server using ORM to get info from my DB and serialize the information in Json to send it to my xamarin App, but when i will deserialize this to object again on my app, I have to manually create a class to each table of my DB. have a way to do the same as in Web.MVC ADO Entity:

[image]

But only get the table structure converted to c# class to can convert back the Json recived from my server.

Thx

Comment: you have your entity classes in your web app, split them out into their own class and reference that from Xamarin app. Don't duplicate code.

Comment: why can't you use `WebApi` ?

Comment: because the server is in PHP using Doctrine with ORM, I exampled with EntityFramework because is a tool I known that generate entity from database to c#.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to ask what you're actually trying to do. So instead of a C# webservice with Entity Framework, you have a PHP webservice using Doctrine? And now you want to do _what_?